# Проблема с установкой драйвера nvidia на ноутбуке

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia

Видеокарта: `Nvidia Geforce 920m`

Система: `Debian 10 buster`

Команда установки драйвера: `sudo su && apt-get install nvidia-driver nvidia-xconfig nvidia-settings`

После того как я установил эти драйвера у меня система нормально запустилась!

`sudo su && nvidia-xconfig && apt-get install nvidia-smi`

А после этой команды у меня появляеться только чёрный экран без всего при старте системы, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

`nvidia-xconfig` создает файл настройки `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` - удали этот файл.

Еще проверь соответствует ли драйвер видеокарте. Какая у вас видеокарта?